# how to append line graph above barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe which have column `age`, `gender` (Male/Female). I want to plot grouped bar plot by Age and want to append line plot of ratio of male to female of each `age`.

`test` is dataframe with `age`, `gender` as column

`ratio_df` is new data frame store ratio of male to female in each `age`

```
ratio_df <- ddply(test, 'age', function(x) c('ratio' = sum(test$gender == 'Male') / sum(test$gender == 'Female')))
```

`ggplot` with barplot and ratio line in `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = factor(age), fill = gender)) + geom_bar() + geom_line(data = ratio_df, aes(x = age, y = ratio))
```

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your ddply call seems off to me - I think it always yields the same ratio (over the whole dataframe).

Comment: I want barplot with test data frame and line plot appended of ratio_df data frame.

Comment: When you create a stacked barplot, where `gender` is represented by different `fill` colours, the ratio of male to female is inherently visible for each stacked bar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, your ddply call seems off to me - I think it always yields the same ratio (over the whole dataframe). I could not figure out a compact elegant one from the top of my head so I had to resort to a somewhat clunky one but it does work.

EDIT: I changed the code to reflect the workaround described by http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-ggplot2:aligntwoplots to adress the OP's comment.

```
#sample data
test=data.frame(gender=c("m","m","f","m","f","f","f"),age=c(1,3,4,4,3,4,4))

require(plyr)
age_N <- ddply(test, c("age","gender"), summarise, N=length(gender))

require(reshape2)
ratio_df <- dcast(age_N, age ~ gender, value.var="N", fill=0)
ratio_df$ratio <- ratio_df$m / (ratio_df$f+ratio_df$m)

#create variables for facetting
test$panel = rep("Distribution",length(test$gender))
ratio_df$panel = rep("Ratio",length(ratio_df$ratio))

test$panel <- factor(test$panel,levels=c("Ratio","Distribution"))

require(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = factor(age)))
g <- g + facet_wrap(~panel,scale="free",ncol=1)
g <- g + geom_line(data = ratio_df, aes(x = factor(age), y = ratio, group=1))
g <- g + geom_bar(aes(fill=gender))
print(g)
```

Is this what you are looking for? However, I think @SvenHohenstein is right that the line does not any information as the split is evident form the fill.

[image]

Comment: Thank for solution. It is working fine but I want to assign right y-axis for line and left y-axis for barplot.

Comment: Two different y axis are not possible in ggplot - see Hadley's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/3124909